# Get all same scripts that attached in scene's gameobjects and store its into array, using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to get all same scripts in scene and then process it in another script is possible to do that?? 
Here is what I tried so far, but unity throws the below error when using it:

```
ScrollingBackgroundScript[] scrollingObjects = FindObjectsOfType (typeof(ScrollingBackgroundScript)) as ScrollingBackgroundScript;
```

The error statement from unity is:

error CS0039: Cannot convert type UnityEngine.Object[] to ScrollingBackgroundScript via a built-in conversion

Comment: Check this [answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/46283/way-to-get-all-object-with-a-certain-componentscri.html), does it do what you need?

Comment: thanks for the answer, i try it before, but it just give me one from the all scripts in scene, what i want is grab all the scripts in scene and then loop it become specific so i can call the method from every specific script, sorry if my question is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the []

```
ScrollingBackgroundScript[] scrollingObjects = FindObjectsOfType (typeof(ScrollingBackgroundScript)) as ScrollingBackgroundScript[];
```

Comment: Thank you, i did not notice about it before.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment (getting only one instead of multiple game objects), I think it may be the case that the other objects are inactive. `FindObjectsOfType` doesn't find inactive objects :)

One solution to this is to use [Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html):

```
var scrollingObjects = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<ScrollingBackgroundScript>();
```

Please notice that it can end up returning more things than you want! (check the documentation).

Comment: Every objects in my scene active, as i know code that you posted above is javascript right? i can't use FindObjecstOfTypeAll in C#. sorry so far i rarely used javascript.

Comment: Also, C# and javascript share the same Unity API, so you should be able to use everything you see on a javascript code, writing C# code.

Comment: yes, sorry i missed Resources, and i tried in my project it's also worked, impressive! but what differences between both solution? or they are same?

Comment: The difference is that it's very common to have  inactive game objects in your game at some point, and this method would get them, if you need all objects. But JinJi's solution is more common and better if you don't need inactive objects or you can guarantee they'll always be active.